# How to get a certain line of a multi-line string

Tags: python

I am trying to get a certain line from a multi-lined string in python, but I can't find a way to do it.

```
s = """Hello
this is my 
long string"""
```

I have tried putting it into a txt file, and working from there, but I don't know very much about how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `s.split('\n')[row_number]`

Comment: "I have tried putting it into a txt file ..." that is a creative idea, but I can't imagine a single instance of a string-processing task which would be aided by taking a string which is already in memory and then writing it to a file for the purpose of rereading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string by the line feed (\n) and you will get an array with all the lines:

```
s = """Hello
this is my 
long string"""

>>> s.split("\n")
['Hello', 'this is my ', 'long string']

#first line
>>> s.split("\n")[0]
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.split('\n')[number]
```

this seems to work